# Remove plugins with vue-cli3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

Is there a way to remove plugins and its configuration with vue-cli3 in an existing project? For example I want to replace unit test plugin Mocha with Jest. I know how to add and invoke a new plugin but I cannot find how to remove one. Is it possible with vue-cli or do I need to do it manually?

Answer (score 20):

I've asked about this ([How does one uninstall a plugin? #2540](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2540)) and it appears the current official advice is to issue an `npm uninstall X`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can just go to your package.json and remove the entry for the plugin/package,

delete the directory of your node_modules,

and then run.

```
npm install
```

Comment: @sven, if this suits you, then accept the answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Delete the vuetify stuff[1] from your package.json and then run:

```
npm prune
```

[1] Dependency `vuetify` and dev dependencies `vue-cli-plugin-vuetify`, `vuetify-loader`...

Comment: also remove sass, sass-loader etc probably.

Comment: Will this update the webpack compiling?  I don't think so.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you need to do it manually, I cannot find anything in the docs or CLI help that mentions removal of plugins. It is slightly more complicated than @alexandre-canijo says though. Besides the package.json there may be some config in your project folder. Check the src/plugins folder, and main.js.

[image: Vue CLI help]

[The documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/plugins-and-presets.html#installing-plugins-in-an-existing-project)

Comment: That is right, since vue-cli performs some edition in files when installing a plugin, by just removing a plugin in node_modules some unnecessary code will remain. I had to uninstall cli-plugin-e2e-cypress (since it behaves weird, I wanted to re install it without vue cli plugin), I created a new project with a first commit an then installed the plugin via vue-cli in order to have a precise list of what files where edited. Then I could go back to my orignal project and delete the unnecessary files.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it manually. It worked for me.

In my case, I just removed the plugin `("vue-cli-plugin-quasar": "^2.0.1",)` from `devDependencies` in `package.json` and ran `npm install`.

Answer (score -3):

With the new "**vue ui**" option, removing installed cli-plugins is supported now.

Under "Dependencies" (second tab on the left of vue ui) you'll find all plugins listed. And on the right of each plugin there is a little trash icon, which removes the respective plugin.

You still might get compile errors due to dead references in your sources, but those can be identified quickly with the provided log and error messages.

Comment: I guess (haven't verified it fully yet) that the advantage in using the UI (once you started managing  your projects that way) is that the plugin should "undo" former changes in the different config files.  
Another option is to commit before adding a plugin and just roll back if you're not happy with it.

Comment: -1 The plugins are listed in the 'Plugins' tab (which doesn't have the trash icon)- they do not appear in the 'Dependencies' tab (v. 3.0.3). It seems you do have to manually uninstall the package.

Comment: very wrong answer